# Debug application when app installed on real device

Tags: android, react-native

Yet another question but I am unable to find the answer to my issue. The application works perfectly in my emulator but not on my android 9 and android 8 devices. When it starts, it shows the spinner that never ends. While I know the application flow, it is still hard for me to figure out what is not working.

Is there a way to debug an application installed on a real device, reading console logs or log messages?

Comment: Have you tried to run directly on device?

Comment: yes, have you build your debug apk? and on that shake the phone and check debug js remotely.

Comment: This official page has all you need. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Answer (score 0):

You have many options, the easiest would probably be using **ADB** (android debug bridge). If your device is on the same network you can use the commands:

1. **adb connect DEVICE_IP**
2. **adb logcat**

Then open your application, your logs will be displayed on your console. You probably did not handle properly app permissions.